# Xpath: Testing values

Tags: xpath

How can I build an XPath expression testing if there's any value "fail" in the property?

For example for this XML it should return "TRUE"

```
<Properties>
  <Property Descriptor="100">1377349460.298</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="101">1</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="24000">fail</Property>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Property Descriptor="100">1377349462.298</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="101">1</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="24000">pass</Property>
</Properties>
```

And for this it should return "FALSE"

```
<Properties>
  <Property Descriptor="100">1377349460.298</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="101">1</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="24000">pass</Property>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Property Descriptor="100">1377349462.298</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="101">1</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="24000">pass</Property>
</Properties>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Documentation is here* [**`Function: boolean boolean(object)`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean)

Yes possible:-

```
boolean(//Property[.='fail'])
```

The above expression for your first xml will return `true` and for the second xml will return `false`.